# Count The Number Of Times Each Instance has been selected from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bit of a dillema. I'm very new to coding but really want to complete this competition app I'm trying to create for my blog. I'm nearly finished except for the last step.

**My Problem**

I need to count the number of times each team has been selected by ALL members.

**My DB Table**

Perhaps if you look at my db table, it will make more sense what I'm trying to do.

[image]

**EXAMPLE**
By looking at the table, the app should read:

`2 users selected the Stormers`
`2 users selected the Kings`
`1 User Selected the Cheetahs`
`1 User Selected the Sunwolves`

AND SO ON

:

I tried to code this by doing the following. (Please don't scrutinize me for not using prepared statements. I'm already struggling, but I'm slowly learning the adjustment.)

```
<?php 
    $sql="SELECT pick,COUNT(DISTINCT(pick)) as nr FROM multiple_picks 
                Where tournament = '$tour' AND  round ='$round'"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $timesSelected = $row['nr'];
        $teamSelected = $row['pick'];

        echo $timesSelected.' Players Selected'. $teamSelected;
    }
    ?>
```

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. The eventual goal is to add this to a chart, but for now just printed statements will do.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will do the trick. it will first group the table by **picks** and then will count the distinct number of users per each pick.

```
select pick,count(distinct(member_nr)) as number_of_users from multiple_picks group by picks where tournament = '$tour' AND  round ='$round'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an sql aggregate function but not using the group by clause.
Also since you need the member count, it should be distinct of member_nr.

> SELECT pick,COUNT(DISTINCT(member_nr)) as nr FROM multiple_picks 
>   WHERE tournament='$tour' AND round='$round'
>   group by pick

Answer (score 0):

Did you validate query?
if it has no problem

```
$sql="SELECT pick,COUNT(DISTINCT(pick)) as nr FROM multiple_picks 
            Where tournament = '".$tour."' AND  round ='".$round."' group by pick";
```

should go like this.
Good luck !